# how to change a selections options based on another select option selected (Array)?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have 2 select options fetched in foreach as many as my records goes. I want to change the drop down options in second select options based on what I select in first select options.

```
<select id="main[{{$user->id}}]">
   <option value="a">A</option>
   <option value="b">B</option>
   <option value="c">C</option>
<select>
```

select option if A is selected from first select option

```
<select id='sub[{{$user->id}}]'>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

I tried the normal method but it works for just the first select

```
$('#main').change(function() {
    var options = '';
    if($(this).val() == 'a') {
        options = '<option value="1">1</option>';
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'b'){
        options = '<option value="2">2</option>';
    }

    $('#sub').html(options);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by `works for just the first select`?

Comment: i have a foreach loop to fetch data for my users so for my first row it work fine but for the others not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

/// inside your foreach loop

```
<select id="main[{{$user->id}}]" class="main">
   <option value="a">A</option>
   <option value="b">B</option>
   <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<select id='sub[{{$user->id}}]' class='sub'>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

/// exit foreach loop

```
<script>
    $('.main').change(function() {
        var options = '';
        if($(this).val() == 'a') {
            options = '<option value="1">1</option>';
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'b'){
            options = '<option value="2">2</option>';
        }

        $(this).next('.sub').html(options);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it gives all sub the same option not a different selection for each row

Comment: @AmrViernes, I am change in my code, can you try again.

Comment: Worked like a charm